# Distances of points between rows with sf

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf

I have multiple trajectories saved in simple feature (`sf`) of the type `POINT`. I'd like to calculate the Euclidean distances between subsequent locations (i.e. rows). Until now, I've "manually" calculated distances using the [Pythagorean formula for calculating Euclidean Distances in 2D space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions). I was wondering if I could do the same using the function `sf::st_distance()`. Here's a quick example:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(
  gr = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)),
  x  = rnorm(10),
  y = rnorm(10)
 )

df <- st_as_sf(df,coords = c("x","y"),remove = F)


df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(
    dist = sqrt((lead(x)-x)^2+(lead(y)-y)^2)
  )
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 4 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -0.8356286 ymin: -2.2147 xmax: 1.595281 ymax: 1.511781
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#> # Groups:   gr [2]
#>    gr         x       y   dist                 geometry
#>    <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>                  <POINT>
#>  1 a     -0.626  1.51    1.38     (-0.6264538 1.511781)
#>  2 a      0.184  0.390   1.44     (0.1836433 0.3898432)
#>  3 a     -0.836 -0.621   2.91   (-0.8356286 -0.6212406)
#>  4 a      1.60  -2.21    3.57        (1.595281 -2.2147)
#>  5 a      0.330  1.12   NA         (0.3295078 1.124931)
#>  6 b     -0.820 -0.0449  1.31  (-0.8204684 -0.04493361)
#>  7 b      0.487 -0.0162  0.992  (0.4874291 -0.01619026)
#>  8 b      0.738  0.944   0.204    (0.7383247 0.9438362)
#>  9 b      0.576  0.821   0.910    (0.5757814 0.8212212)
#> 10 b     -0.305  0.594  NA       (-0.3053884 0.5939013)
```

I would like to calculate `dist` with `sf::st_distance()`. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first thing to know about `sf` is that the geometry column (the one of class `sfc`) is stored as a list-column inside the dataframe. The key to *usually* do anything with a list-column is to either use `purrr::map` and friends or to use a function that accepts list-cols as arguments. In the case of `st_distance` its arguments can be an object of `sf` (a dataframe), `sfc` (the geometry column), or even an `sfg` (a single geom row), so there's no need for `map` and friends. The solution should look something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(
    dist = st_distance(geometry)
  )
```

However, this doesn't work. After some investigating, we find two problems. First, `st_distance` returns a distance matrix and not a single value. To solve this, we make use of the `by_element = T` argument of `st_distance`.

Next, we can't just do `dist = st_distance(geometry, lead(geometry), by_element = T)` because `lead` only works on vector columns, not list columns.

To solve this second problem, we create the lead column ourselves using `geometry[row_number() + 1]`.

Here's the full solution:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr) %>%
  mutate(
    lead = geometry[row_number() + 1],
    dist = st_distance(geometry, lead, by_element = T),
  )
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 4 fields
#> Active geometry column: geometry
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -0.8356286 ymin: -2.2147 xmax: 1.595281 ymax: 1.511781
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   gr [2]
#>    gr         x       y  dist                       geometry
#>    <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>         <sf_geometry [degree]>
#>  1 a     -0.626  1.51   1.38     POINT (-0.6264538 1.511781)
#>  2 a      0.184  0.390  1.44     POINT (0.1836433 0.3898432)
#>  3 a     -0.836 -0.621  2.91   POINT (-0.8356286 -0.6212406)
#>  4 a      1.60  -2.21   3.57        POINT (1.595281 -2.2147)
#>  5 a      0.330  1.12   0         POINT (0.3295078 1.124931)
#>  6 b     -0.820 -0.0449 1.31  POINT (-0.8204684 -0.04493361)
#>  7 b      0.487 -0.0162 0.992  POINT (0.4874291 -0.01619026)
#>  8 b      0.738  0.944  0.204    POINT (0.7383247 0.9438362)
#>  9 b      0.576  0.821  0.910    POINT (0.5757814 0.8212212)
#> 10 b     -0.305  0.594  0       POINT (-0.3053884 0.5939013)
#> # ... with 1 more variable: lead <sf_geometry [degree]>
```

Comment: Thank you for not just sharing your solution, but also the thoughts that went into it. Makes this answer invaluable!

Comment: I don't know when it happened, but `lead()` and `lag()` now work with lists. So you could just write `dist = st_distance(geometry, lead(geometry), by_element = T)` within `mutate()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base `R` solution. The trick is to

1. `split()` the dataframe by the group column
2. On each group

   - calculate the distance between subsequent locations using `head()` and `tail()`
   - append `NA` to the result (since the last position does not have a subsequent location)
3. Bind the resulting `sf` objects back together using `rbind` in `do.call()`.

```r
split(df, df$gr) |> 
  lapply(\(x){
    x$dist <- c(st_distance(head(x,-1), tail(x,-1),by_element = TRUE), NA)
    x
  }) |> 
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```